# Is there a way to sync contacts between an android phone and an iPad without using a computer?

Tags: icloud, backup

If I use a computer, then I can log into iCloud to download all my contacts, copy them to google and sync between gmail and the android phone.

Is there a way to do this without a computer and just extract all my contacts from iPad and then send the file containing all my contacts to myself as an email, so I can download the file from gmail? Without a computer, it seems all I can do is extract contacts one at a time.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you keep all of your contacts in google contacts and use google apps on both the iPad and Android phone, then you wouldn't need iCloud.  Why do you use iCloud?

Comment: Google drive syncs almost everything. If you sync contacts with your Gmail account on Android, then you can also sync them on iOS and you can also use Google Photos to sync photos across all devices

Comment: @BrettDikeman Please don‘t second guess the intentions of the OP. If you know of a way to transfer contacts from iOS to Android just provide an answer (be it with iCloud or without.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As comments have alluded to, if you go to Settings > Passwords & Accounts on your iOS device, you can select "Add Account" and add your Google account there.  Once you set that up, you can configure it to sync contacts (and email, calendar, etc) to your Google account.